Is it normal to see stacked single switches instead of three in a three-gang box?
We're building a new house, and the placement of the light switches in the rooms looks unusual to me. When I asked the builder about it, he said it's standard and normal, but it just doesn't seem right. Is this something that's common in the Dallas area?


"Safe" - sure (probably, assuming the out-of-sight workmanship is up-to-scratch). "Normal" ... hardly. And tbh I'd be suspicious of the workmanship considering that those  switches are not even mounted in-line with each other... And what's up with that white wire dangling out he hole in the wall? Thermostat?

Usually when you are building a new house you tell the builder where you want the switches placed.  Have you indicated your preference?  And what is that cable coming out of the wall?!

Wonder if there is not enough space for a three gang.  Boxes are mounted to studs, so might only have space for a two gang, plus one above/below.  An inspection camera in the top hole might show something blocking a 3 gang.

@MichaelHall we did not indicate any preference on where want the switches to be. I'm guessing the cable is for thermostat

I hope it's a small thermostat, because it's really close to the top switch. This looks like crap, but that's an opinion not an answer.

I love that the screws are all perfectly aligned but the boxes aren't.  :(.....

The builder usually follows a specification.  Or asks you.  This is very ugly, and I wouldn't accept it in a new home.  Maybe a 3-gang box wouldn't fit there but there are double and triple switches for one gang so you can do whatever you want. You haven't painted yet so break it open and make it nicer.

This question is a matter of opinion and local trends. Mine is that I'd have used a triple switch in a single box if space was limited.

Have never worked in Dallas but have worked in hundreds of subdivisions in other states and have never seen this. Nothing wrong with it, just looks weird. What I have seen is three switch combo units installed. See picture below from Home Depot.  These can be installed vertical or horizontal and they look a lot better. They are available in single pole, but not in 3-way.

the

You've never seen light switches poorly chosen, randomly located and misaligned?  Of course you have. :)

@jay613   OK, yes I have, but not all at the same time and in the same place in such a small space.. :-)

@jay613 They're not random if the stud they're mounted to is at an angle...

@EngineerToast oh how sad I think you're right.    A 4 degree angle.  And the same finisher who aligned the screws also made each switch vertical using the play in the plaster ears.  So they are parallel to the door but jog away from it.

I'd like to see all the wiring jammed into a single box!

The problem with this setup is you're probably going to blow up the box fill limits of the box behind it. To which I say 4-11/16" box (42 ci) + 1-gang mud ring.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica  Exactly.   It's how I used to do GFCI's  too.

A triple-switch is the most compact solution. However, the builder (or more likely, the electrical subcontractor) might be concerned about:

Box Fill - There is a limit to how many wires/cables and devices can fit in a box. Depending on the situation, that can result in either needing multiple boxes or using deeper/larger boxes than typical.
3-Way or 4-Way Switches - These are switches where more than one switch controls a single light. They are commonly used in large rooms with multiple entrances, hallways and stairways. Triple switches are generally three single switches and can't be used where 3-way or 4-way switches are needed.
Smart Switches - Smart switches, timers, dimmers, etc. generally require a full gang for each switch. That isn't the case here, but it could be the builder is anticipating future upgrades and therefore putting each switch in a separate box.

However, even if there is not enough room for three switches side-by-side, which is actually quite plausible based on the picture, a 3-gang box can be rotated 90-degrees. That will require a little more width than a single vertical box, but not that much, and will look much better, with a proper 3-gang faceplate, than the current mess.


The second & third bullets point re 3/4-way & smart switches are a little fuzzy to me. Are 3/4-way & smart switches too big to fit in a double- or triple-gang box/faceplate?

@Triplefault Read the whole item. The problem is smart and 3 and 4 ways are not available in triple format to fit 3 in one box.

I did read it all....  I thought "triple-switch" meant "triple-gang switch", like you show, rotated, in your picture. The triple-switch isn't in your answer, it's in Jack's. So the connection is not obvious.

@Triplefault Sorry about the confusion. Triple-switch is in the very beginning of my answer and then this is one of the reasons why a triple-switch (as in Jack's answer, and as in my bathrooms) might not always work.

No problem! I did see "triple switch" at the start of your answer & though it meant what the picture showed. Thanks for clarifying!
